# How do I exclude a protected method from javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

How do I exclude a protected method from javadoc?

I need to document some but not all protected methods.

Thanks

Comment: put @hide in the doc above your method

Comment: Oh my god so there was such a tag. Why do then all documentation and tutorials on internet say there is no such tag and you have to write complex stuff to make another solution for this.

Comment: Actually, no I get error @hide is an unknown tag.

Comment: I guess it is specific to android, then, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why the don't have this.

Comment: because android has a special idea about java

Comment: As to why there is no hide switch in javadoc... A protected method of a documented class is considered part of the API. If it shouldn't be documented, it probably shouldn't be accessible, so it doesn't belong exposed like that.

Comment: This question is closely related to my question: [is-there-a-way-to-produce-javadoc-for-a-subset-of-public-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812349/is-there-a-way-to-produce-javadoc-for-a-subset-of-public-methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude **all** protected methods with the command line option ["-protected"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#protected), but I just re-read your question more closely and realize this is probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with straight Javadoc but, depending on what other javadoc facilities you need, and how it is you are generating your javadoc, you could consider switching to **Doclava**.  Doclava is a doclet (think: plug-in) for javadoc and it *does* recognise the @hide tag.

The HTML output is much prettier too.

Unfortunately it *doesn't* recognise large swathes of javadoc command line options, so it may not be suitable.

https://code.google.com/p/doclava/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the maven plugin, you can use the **show** tag into the *configuration* tag with value **public** as shown below. In that case, only public members of classes will be displayed into javadoc.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <show>public</show>
                <doctitle>My company API</doctitle>
                <subpackages>my.company.package.api</subpackages>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```